# How Do I Refuse a Request to a Subdomain in Nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

If my configuration looks something like

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
}
```

how do I refuse requests to subdomain.example.com?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    deny all;
}
```

Or, if you wanted to drop all traffic that wasn't to a domain explicitly defined in another `server` block in your config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shane Madden's answer will work, or you may also use the non-standard response code 444, which will kill the connection without sending any headers (source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

To block specific subdomains:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
        return 444;
}
```

Or to block all subdomains or domains that are not handled elsewhere:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

The latter option is useful when blocking domains that are duplicating your content and thus may hurt your search engine rankings. (This comes from personal experience.)

Answer (score 1):

If your subdomain have trafic, better redirect all request from subdomain to domain
like this

```
        if ($http_host != "example.com") {
            rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

in server section

It's SEO friendly.

Comment: In this case that's explicitly what I don't want to do though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can return 404 http code which  refused subdomain like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain1.example.com subdomain2.example.com;
    return 404;
}
```